# Tool / accelerator for improving adding css and script resources to MVC3 Razor pages

Tags: javascript, css, resources, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is there any tool to make adding files to MVC3 razor pages faster?

I find myself having to drag script files onto the page to generate:

`<script src="../../Scripts/rails.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Which then i'll copy and paste

`<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/")" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Then cut/drag the `rails.js` fragment into the new script statement. Then at some point after this hopefully I remember I need to clean up a whole bunch of duplicated and/or broken script links.

There has to be a better way than this that doesn't involve typing urls out manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came across this blog post earlier today and [ASP.NET MVC Best Practices (Part 1)](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx#urlHelperExtension) and it's guidance shows

```
public static string Image(this UrlHelper helper, string fileName)
{
    return helper.Content("~/assets/images/{0}".FormatWith(fileName));
}

public static string Stylesheet(this UrlHelper helper, string fileName)
{
    return helper.Content("~/assets/stylesheets/{0}".FormatWith(fileName));
}

public static string NoIcon(this UrlHelper helper)
{
    return Image(helper, "noIcon.png");
}
```

This seems like the optimal solution if you use a good layout scheme for your resources.

**Edit:** FWIW

```
public static string FormatWith(this string format, params object[] inputs)
{
    return string.Format(format, inputs)
}
```

Comment: is that FormatWith() your extension?

Comment: Ironically both yes and no. That was a sample straight from that blog post however I do directly have a .FormatWith extension in all of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC)** to get a compile-time validation your your links.

> **2.3. Strongly typed links to script files and static resources**
>
> T4MVC generates static helpers for
>   your content files and script files.
>   So instead of writing:

```
<img src="/Content/nerd.jpg" />
```

> You
>   can write:

```
<img src="<%= Links.Content.nerd_jpg %>" />
```

> Likewise, instead of

```
<script src="/Scripts/Map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

> You
>   can write

```
<script src="<%= Links.Scripts.Map_js %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

> The obvious benefit is that you’ll get
>   a compile error if you ever move or
>   rename your static resource, so you’ll
>   catch it earlier.
>
> Another benefit is that you get a more
>   versatile reference. When you write
>   src="/Content/nerd.jpg", your app will
>   only work when it’s deployed at the
>   root of the site. But when you use the
>   helper, it executes some server side
>   logic that makes sure your reference
>   is correct wherever your site is
>   rooted. It does this by calling
>   VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/nerd.jpg").

Comment: That doesn't really help my problem since that just trades 1 type of string wrangling for another type of string wrangling. I've used T4MVC in the past and found it to be completely worthless. It always seemed to add an extra hoop to jump through and never once helped me. Couple this with times I forgot to right click < run custom tool to regenerate the T4 files having caused broken production deployments left me with a very poor view of T4MVC and I personally will probably never use it again, nor would I recommend it to anyone.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I always deploy to production from a CI server, so if something doesn't work I can catch it before users.

Comment: A CI server wouldn't help you in anyway unless it was running WaitN tests that would catch runtime errors.